# RPC giving error -13

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

Bitcoin rpc calls giving error

-13: Error: Please enter the wallet passphrase with walletpassphrase first.

Answer (score 3):

Your wallet is locked with a passphrase, first you need to unlock it before executing commands related to private keys using [walletpassphrase](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/wallet/walletpassphrase/):

```
# Unlock the wallet for 60 seconds
$ bitcoin-cli walletpassphrase "my pass phrase" 60

# Some transaction commands ...

# Lock the wallet again (before 60 seconds)
$ bitcoin-cli walletlock
```

Comment: i am running the bitcoind-cli in regtest also i have not added any passphrase

Comment: The wallet is protected with a password. You can always delete your regtest files and start over

Comment: when i have  first time started the reg test at that time i have not created any wallet passphrase , if there is already wallet passphrase created then how can i see that , Is there is any conf file that store the wallet passphrase ?